# Caching ending and beginning of month in Mysql. Mysql variables redefinition in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, query-optimization

I am writing a statistics application and I need to interrogate a database for the monthly revenue of a client so i need to see how many days of each subscription are in that month. Problem is I need to tell him the start and the end of the last month and I can't send my system time because of the clock difference. It needs to be it's own. I can't use variables from Mysql because it will be subject to multiple queries and from what I know they can be overridden and cause errors.

```
SELECT GREATEST ( LEAST ( x.period_end, y.period_end) - GREATEST ( x.period_start, y.period_start), 0 ) 
from customer_invoice x, (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AS period_start, 
LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) AS period_end) y;
```

I need to know if there is any way to explicitly tell Mysql to calculate 'y' once and use it. Or if i can tell him to use variables that correspond to a single Mysql request.

I am using a wrapper of Mysql wrote over the standard one from Node.js and from what i know if a query defines a variable and is executing and another query comes along and tries to define a variable with the same name it overrides the first corrupting the first query. I could use custom hashed names for each variable but I don't want to go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do once:

```
SELECT @foo := this + that,
       @bar := other * stuff;
```

Use those @variables as often as needed:

```
SELECT ... @foo ... @bar .. @foo
```

They will be lost at the end of the session (when you disconnect).

**Addenda**

`@variables` are local to the session (that is, local to the connection).  So each connection can work with different values.

Comment: yes but what happens when 2 queries execute at the same time and require different values for the @foo variable?